# Where clause with dates in hive

Tags: hive

The where clause in the below hive query is not working

```
 select
 e.num as badge
from dbo.events as e
 where  TO_DATE(e.event_time_utc) > TO_DATE(select event_date from DL_EDGE_LRF_facilities.card_swipes_lastpulldate)
```

both event_time_utc and event_date fields are defined as strings and event_time_utc has timestamp values like '2017-09-18 20:10:19.000000' and event_date has only one date value like '2018-01-25' 
 i am getting an error like "cannot recognize input near '`select`' '`event_date`' 'from' in function specification " when i run the query, Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@user86683; hive does not recognize the syntax since it does not allow in-query in the inequality condition (>). You may try this query and let me know the result.

```
select e.num as badge
from dbo.events as e, DL_EDGE_LRF_facilities.card_swipes_lastpulldate c
where  TO_DATE(e.event_time_utc) > TO_DATE(c.event_date)
```

You will get a warning but you may ignore it since the table for event_date has only one record.

```
Warning: Map Join MAPJOIN[10][bigTable=e] in task 'Map 1' is a cross product
Query ID = xxx_20180201102128_aaabb2235-ee69275cbec1
Total jobs = 1
Launching Job 1 out of 1
Status: Running (Executing on YARN cluster with App id application_09fdf345)
```

Hope this helps. Thanks.